# Dropbox Request URL path to file C#

Tags: c#, rest, http-headers, uwp, dropbox-api

I have OneDrive & Google Drive successfully processing chunked download however Dropbox is giving me grief because I cannot get the correct http request path to the file.

I am not an expert in rest url's & endpoints, maybe someone can point me in the right direction for the acceptable dropbox request format for the latest UWP SDK.

```
using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage())
{
    string url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto" + uri;

    string accessKey = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[CommonData.dropboxAccessToken_Key].ToString();

    httpRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
    httpRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
    httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessKey);
}
```

I have read docs on Dropbox and it is not clear on the formatting for me, also I could not find a clear example anywhere.

Thanks again!

Comment: Did you check this doc https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial?

Comment: I saw that, I want to download chucked due to memory limitations, I want to do it the http rest way.  I believe that v1 only supports chucked download. Thanks

Comment: Dropbox API v2 does support range retrieval requests on content-download endpoints: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats such as https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download

Comment: @Greg, thanks for the comment, I remember seeing in the docs that it was not ready for production, besides v1 worked v2 didn't. Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, the problem here is in your authorization header. For Dropbox API, the correct authorization header should like following:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access token>
```

So we should change `httpRequest.Headers.Authorization` to

```
httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Then your code should be albe to work. Using "file.mp3" under "temp" folder for example.
[image]

The code may like:

```
var uri = "/temp/file.mp3";
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage())
    {
        string url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto" + Uri.EscapeDataString(uri);

        httpRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        httpRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
        httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay Zuo, debugging shows authorisation is fine, the error I get is in the HttpResponseMessgae which is "404 Not Found" so that should mean that the path to the file is incorrect. I need to find an example of a path doing the same thing.  Thanks

Comment: @SeanRyan Where is the file you want to retrieve? Using "Get Started with Dropbox.pdf" under the root folder for example, the url should be `https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto/Get Started with Dropbox.pdf`. Besides, you may need to URI encode the path in the URL like:`string url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto" + Uri.EscapeDataString(uri);`.

Comment: Jay Zuo, it should be "https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto/temp/file.mp3" I will try URL encoding the path and reply later. Thanks

Comment: @SeanRyan I've added a simple sample in my answer. It works well in my side, please have a check. ;)

Comment: Thanks Jay Zuo, I will test in a few hours.

Comment: thanks yes everything was correct apart from Url encoded path, thanks again.